# Jasper: Removes Logo and some Jasper menus from Dashboard on Iframe?

Tags: php, html, css, jasperserver

I have the same problem as you, I want to have a report in Jasper Report. I called the Report to **my PHP application** with **Iframe**, but **I intend to remove the logo and some of the menus on the dashboard**, I tried to add additional CSS to Override.CSS but it didn't work when running on Iframe. Do you think there are other ways I can do to solve this problem?

*This is the code I use to call Jasper via Iframe:*

```
<iframe src=<?php echo $iFrameSRC; ?> height="<?php echo $iFrameHeight; ?>" width="100%" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

This is my Iframe display

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the [embedded](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/embedding-using-http-api) option? There are parameters like hiding menus (decorate = no). There is also the option to use the [rest_v2/reports API service](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-rest-api-reference/v630/reports-service), but it returns the report and does not provide this Jasper server dashboard.

Comment: If you didn't need the Jasper Server dashboard, or create your own dashboard, you could use the [JasperPHP](https://github.com/cossou/JasperPHP) package (uses the [JasperStarter](http://jasperstarter.cenote.de/) command line launcher) to generate the reports.

Comment: Its working bro, Thankyou so much
but, when I want to run my report in Iframe the jasper dasboard back again after Refresh

Comment: Make sure the parameter is set after refresh. Try with the `viewAsDashboardFrame=true` parameter that I mentioned in my answer. If it doesn't work, check if there is no new version that solves this problem.

Comment: Thankyou bro for your answere its help full, but its actually not working after refresh again, and I has been found solution for it, I'm using Embeded Theme and add it to jasper, so Its very helpfull
Thankyou somuch

Answer (score 0):

There are parameters for that:

> **decorate=no** Attribute that hides menus.
>
> ---
>
> **viewAsDashboardFrame=true** Attribute that signifies only the dashboard
>     should be rendered (pre 6.0 dashboards only).

For more details, check out this [documentation](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/embedding-using-http-api).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou bro for your answere its help full, but its actually not working after refresh again, and I has been found solution for it, I'm using ** Embeded Theme** and add it to jasper, so Its very helpfull
Thankyou somuch

Comment: Great! Good to know!